# AWS - How to cloud convert any video or image format into MP4 or JPG?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image-processing, jpeg, mp4, video-processing

I am looking for a cloud-based solution where our user can `upload` any kind of `image` or `video` file format as per their wish but we wanted it to convert it into `jpg` or `mp4` respectively.

For example:

**Image** : Any kind of file as an input should convert into **JPG**.

**Video** : Any kind of file as an input should convert into **MP4**.

**Question:** 
Is there any *3rd* party service available by either `AWS` or any other `cloud services provider` than would be an easier for us to adopt early?

**NOTE -** `Quality` should not be lost due to this operation.

Comment: Asking for recommendations for tools, libraries and off-site resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow so I'm voting to close. FWIW, **ImageMagick** for images, `ffmpeg` for video.

Comment: Not clear... Your title asks how to convert a format A into format B (for which FFmpeg tool is the answer) but later you change topic to "Is there AWS option or some other cloud service to convert formats?". Which one are you looking for? If staying within AWS system then try: [**AWS media convert**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=aws+media+format+conversion). Another Google search is: [**encode media cloud service**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=+encode+media+cloud+service)

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged `Amazon-web-sevices` consider using their own
[Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/).

Other AWS ideas :

- [Serverless image handler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/).
- [Image Conversion using Amazon Lambda and S3 in Node.js](http://jice.lavocat.name/blog/2015/image-conversion-using-amazon-lambda-and-s3-in-node.js/).

There is no managed service for image conversion, but for videos then ElasticTranscoder might work.
Though, at high volumes you would probably go with EC2 instance which uses some kind of library for converting. Managed solutions on AWS doesnt yet have range of possibilities to convert everything. You will need to still use some custom code